# Is there a way to make my computers fans turn on instead of the CPU dropping frequency? I'm using Linux Mint 19.3

Tags: cpu, cpu-frequency, temperature, lscpu, cpulimit

My computer, for whatever reason, will lower CPU usage when it gets hot instead of turning on its fan. I don't know if it's a driver issue or something else. Thanks! [image: This is at 80 Celcius]

The above is at 80 degrees Celcius.

Comment: The computer is a laptop and device manager doesn't want to open.

Comment: What laptop model is this? Typically you can adjust the fan activity inside the BIOS, which can usually be reached by pressing Del or F10/F12 after you power on the laptop.

Comment: It's an ASUS VivoBook X541SA. I will give that a try, but I've explored the BIOS and I haven't seen anything fan related.

Comment: I scoured the BIOS for 20 minutes and found no fan anything. Is there some "sudo apt-get install" command that I can run to get some control? There is nothing in Linux Mint 19.3 settings that I can find that will do it.

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get install fancontrol, but for some reason, I can't run it. Linux "can't read the configuration file."

Comment: You need to run `sudo sensors-detect` before to generate a configuration file. Afterwards run `sudo pwmconfig`. Check https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control, which is for Arch Linux, but the program usage applies to Mint as well.

Comment: BTW: Does the fan run when you're inside the BIOS or do you possibly have a dual-boot setup with MS Windows? That way you could check if the fan actually still works - sometimes fans inside older laptops get defective and need to be replaced.

Comment: The fans will turn on, but it is barely noticeable. I would prefer good performance over my PC being quiet. I get about 19 frames on Minecraft, 3 on servers, but the PC thermal throttles instead of getting loud.